# Netlogo: Nothing named edge has been defined

Tags: netlogo

I am new to netlogo(version: 6.1.1). I just wanted to create a patch which goes around the origin. But it reminded me that "Nothing named edge has been defined."

```
to setup-center
  clear-all
  ask patches [
  if pxcor = (- (edge / 2)) and pycor >= (- (edge / 2)) and pycor <= (0 + (edge / 2))
  [set pcolor red]
  if pycor = (- (edge / 2)) and pxcor >= (- (edge / 2)) and pxcor <= (0 + (edge / 2))
  [set pcolor red]
  if pxcor = (edge / 2) and pycor >= (- (edge / 2)) and pycor <= (0 + (edge / 2))
  [set pcolor red]
  if pycor = (edge / 2) and pxcor >= (- (edge / 2)) and pxcor <= (0 + (edge / 2))
  [set pcolor red]
  ]
end
```

Could you please tell me where it went wrong? Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `edge` is not defined in NelLogo.  Rather the edges of the world are described by `min-pxcor`, `max-pxcor`, `min-pycor` and `max-pycor`.  So, your procedure (slightly simplified) would be

```
to setup-center
  clear-all
  let top max-pycor / 2
  let bottom min-pycor / 2
  let left-side min-pxcor / 2
  let right-side max-pxcor / 2
  ask patches [
    if pxcor = left-side and pycor >= bottom and pycor <= (0 + top)
    [set pcolor red]
    if pycor = bottom and pxcor >= left-side and pxcor <= (0 + right-side)
    [set pcolor red]
    if pxcor = right-side and pycor >= bottom and pycor <= (0 + top)
    [set pcolor red]
    if pycor = top and pxcor >= left-side and pxcor <= (0 + right-side)
    [set pcolor red]
  ]
end
```

This approach queries every patch in the world and, if the world is large, is relatively inefficient.  However, for reasonably small worlds it works well and in a setup you are only doing it once.

Hope this helps,
Charles

Comment: It has been resolved already. Thanks for your help, professor